# learning pylons now, in django, how easy is it to use sqlalchemy and a different view engine?

Tags: python, django

learning pylons now, in django, how easy is it to use sqlalchemy and a different view engine?

Is it hackery or its really easy?

That's pretty much the only reason I am using pylons over django.

But I like that fact that django has a bigger community and easier to get answers to issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric Florenzano gave a great talk about this at PyCon this year called "Using Django in Non-Standard Ways." You can find the slides [here](http://media.eflorenzano.com/dropbox/UsingDjangoInNonStandardWays.pdf) (.pdf) and the video of the presentation [here](http://python.mirocommunity.org/video/1198/using-django-in-non-standard-w). All in all I would say that it's not impossibly hard but you will find some difficulty in using pluggable applications (which is part of what makes the community so great) and the Django admin which are both major selling points for Django.